# Insert a string variable as a key (child) in firebase (JAVA)

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have gone through the official documentation of Firebase but I am still confused regarding how can I insert a string variable as a child and set the value of that child. I need the keys to be dynamic. Currently, I am trying to implement this -

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
String email = "abc@example.com";

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference dbRef = database.getReference("connections").child(uid);
dbRef.child(email).setValue("true");
```

Ideally, this should create a new node inside table 'connections' with the current uid, create a child attribute 'abc@example.com' inside this node and set the value to true. Like this-

```
\connections
  -uid
   -abc@example.com: true
```

I have tried this but it's failing. Can anyone point out my mistake and correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you can save the email address of the user as a key in the Firebase real-time database because it contains forbidden characters like `.`. If you still want to use the email address, I suggest you encode it like this:

> name@email.com -> name@email,com

As you probably see, instead of `.` I have used `,`. To achieve this, you can use the following methods:

```
static String encodeUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    return userEmail.replace(".", ",");
}

static String decodeUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    return userEmail.replace(",", ".");
}
```

However, a more appropriate approach would be to use the `uid` that comes from the authentication process. The main benefit would be that the `uid` will never change while the user might change the email address and unfortunately, you cannot simply change the name of a key.